# Service Fabric Stateful Service Dependency Injection with parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-service-fabric

I have an Asp.net Core Stateful service that need to refer to an Interface IUser with dependency Injection.

The IUser interface is implemented by a UserRepository class:

```
    public class UserRepository : IUser
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;
    private IUtility _utility;
    public UserRepository(IMemoryCache memoryCache, IUtility utility)
    {

        _cache = memoryCache;
        _utility = utility;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the User using the Internal ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id"></param>
    /// <param name="useCache"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string Id, bool useCache = true)
    {
          //Find the user and use cache and utilities methods
    }
}
```

In the **MyStateful.cs** file I can successfully add the reference to the Constructor as I would in a Stateless service:

```
 internal sealed class MyStateful: StatefulService
{
    private readonly IUser _user;
    public MyStateful(StatefulServiceContext context, IUser user)
        : base(context)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

}
```

In Program.cs I have the problem:

```
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("MyStatefulType",
context => new MyStateful(context, new UserRepository())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

With error **There is no argument give that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'memoryCache' of UserRepository(IMemoryCache, IUtility)**

Without DI in UserRepository (with a parameter-less constructor) it all works, while in a stateless service I declare eventual dependencies in the **Startup.cs** file like:

```
 services.AddScoped<IUser, UserRepository>();
```

and all is taken care of in the Constructor.

How can I make this work in a Stateful Service too?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/s-innovations/S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.Unity  https://alexmg.com/introducing-the-autofac-integration-for-service-fabric/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Autofac.Integration.ServiceFabric. It's an Autofac extension with support for Service Fabric. Registration in Program.cs will look like:

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterServiceFabricSupport();
    builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUser>();
    builder.RegisterStatefulService<MyStateful>("MyStatefulType");
    using (builder.Build())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

More information on it: https://alexmg.com/posts/introducing-the-autofac-integration-for-service-fabric